# Regex doesn't work in String.find() in Java

Tags: java, regex

I have this small piece of code wherein I want to check if my String contains any of these special characters <, &, >, " '

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(".[<>&'"]");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(value);
if(!matcher.find())
{
found = true;
}
```

The above code is supposed to make found should be true, but it does not work for all inputs

For instance, these inputs values worked well ABCD12345678912345<", ABCD12345678912345<', ABCD12345678912345<"&

But it does not work if input is single character like if input is <, >, ", ', &

Any suggestions.

Comment: Your code doesn't compile.

Comment: Remove the dot from the front of the expression.  And escape the double quote.

Comment: Your regex says that the string must have two characters.  The first is any character (the `.` in the regex matches any character).  The second is a character in the set you've given.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("[<>&'\"]");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(value);
if(matcher.find())
{
   found = true;
}
```